# How do I call a method as an argument in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I've been reading up on different ways to pass methods in Ruby, it seems the cleanest to me to pass the method and execute on it. However, I think I'm doing it incorrectly. This works:

```
def core
  myMethod = rand(2) > 0 ? meth1 : meth2
  myMethod.call("entered val")
end

def meth1
  Proc.new do | val |
    puts "meth1: #{val}"
  end
end

def meth2
  Proc.new do | val |
    puts "meth2: #{val}"
  end
end
```

But it feels more natural to have it look like the below (which doesn't work):

```
def core
  myMethod = rand(2) > 0 ? meth1 : meth2
  myMethod("entered val")
end

def meth1
  puts "meth1: #{val}"
end

def meth2
  puts "meth2: #{val}"
end
```

How do I format the latter so it works properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second example doesn't work because you are actually calling `meth1` and `meth2` from `core` in your ternary operator. You can use the [`Object#method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Object.html#method-i-method) method to make a `Method` object instance out of your individual methods. Wow. That's a lot of using the word `method`. Example code:

```
def core
  myMethod = rand(2) > 0 ? method(:meth1) : method(:meth2)
  myMethod.call("entered val")
end

def meth1(val)
  puts "meth1: #{val}"
end

def meth2(val)
  puts "meth2: #{val}"
end

core
# => "meth1: entered val" (or "meth2: entered val")
```

Another option would be to use [`Object#public_send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Object.html#method-i-public_send) or [`Object#send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Object.html#method-i-send) like so:

```
def core
  myMethod = rand(2) > 0 ? :meth1 : :meth2
  send(myMethod, "entered val")
end

def meth1(val)
  puts "meth1: #{val}"
end

def meth2(val)
  puts "meth2: #{val}"
end
```

Prefer `public_send` if your method visibility allows it.

Comment: Rather than toss out code, explain why it should be done this way. Then the OP will be able to learn what to do and WHY to do it.

Comment: I think there's value to providing a quick, code-only answer to a recently asked question then following up with a long-form explanation as an edit when time allows. You are, of course, welcome to disagree.